# Looking for a book: brother and sister (might be orphans / on the run) holding some kind of a digital book that teaches them everything

Tags: story-identification

This was a book I read when I was a child, so it is a bit flexible on the details.

The story held a part about a brother and a sister (might be orphans / on the run) holding some kind of a digital book that has a connection to a central education center with paid actors that work there and in a "real time" manner sends video(s) to that book, teaching the kids.

That digital book also held some kind of AI that helped the kids learn better...

It might be some ancient book that belong to my father, he can't recall... :(

Comment: Could you give us a more accurate date? We don't know your age so have no idea of when you were a child. It isn't Neal Stephenson's _Diamond Age_ by any chance, is it?

Comment: Was this book in English or another language?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218059/book-featuring-a-child-learning-from-a-crowdsourced-ai-book (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 21):

While not a perfect match, Neal Stephenson's [The Diamond Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Diamond_Age) has some similitudes.

> In fact there are two books, one is created for the daughter of a rich man in a Victorian-like social group, while the other is stolen by a poor guy who gives it to his sister.

Some tips about the society that may help to recognize if it is the same book:

> It is a futuristic society, nations are no longer relevant but people organize themselves in "afine" groups around the world. Matter is not important, thanks to nanotechnology anyone can build anything; what is important are the designs to produce the goods. Even the poor people have a nano-producing machine at home, but they have a limited supply of nanites with which build things.

And for the plot

> The poor girl that receives the book runs out of home with his brother, the girl is "adopted" by the Victorian group but his brother is not allowed due to his criminal history; the actress voicing the book (who learns about her situation due to the text she is told to speak) tries to locate the girl, and joins some weird technocult who can decrypt communications, and they all get caught in a Chinese nationalist surge (as usual with Mr. Stephenson's books, the end is quite confusing and sort of a *deus ex machina*)

Comment: lol, just posted that as a comment. No siblings as I recall though.

Comment: @terdon there were two siblings, a boy who stole the book from the technic that -illegaly- made a duplicate, and his sister who received the book. The brother did not use it at all, though.

Comment: Ah, yes! I really should re-read this, it's been ages and it blew my mind as a kid. Thanks.